# ASP.NET MVCでPOSTした後にModelのSelectListItemがnullになる。

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

あるモデルがSelectListItemのプロパティをもっておりGETで、このプロパティに値を入れるとします。
次にPostすると、Controller側に帰ってくるときにSelectListItemがnullで帰ってきます。

この場合、どのような対応をするのが一番良いでしょうか。
私が考えているのは以下の通りです。
1. Getで行った処理と同じSelectListItemに値を入れることをする。
2. Get時点でTempDataなどに一度退避しておき、Post時点でTempDataから値をもらう。

その他に方法があればご教授ください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのモデルがどういClassなのか、行いたい処理のロジックも
はっきりわからないので非常に回答しづらいと思います。

もし、Get でクライアントに送ったデータをPost処理でサーバに取りたいのなら
Post処理専用の ViewModel を作るとよいのではないかと思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。また連絡が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。アドバイスいただいた通り、ViewModelを作成する方法を取りました。

Answer (score 0):

余計なお世話かもしれませんが、これ「GETで、このプロパティに値を入れるとします。」がそもそも良くないのでは？

これは削除の質問で、質問自身でも書いていますが。
[asp.net-mvc submit 仕組み - GETではなく、HTTP POSTまたはDELETEを使用して削除する必要があるのはなぜですか?](https://code.i-harness.com/ja/q/bfe96)

> いくつかの方法（例えば、HEAD、GET、OPTIONS、TRACE）は安全と定義されています。つまり、情報の取得のみを目的としており、サーバーの状態を変更すべきではありません。

---

@松田俊さん回答の対応も組み合わせて、以下のように考えられると思います。

1.SelectListItemが変更を許す値の場合。

POSTを行う際に クライアント側でJavaScriptによる値の有効性チェック処理を組み込んでおく。
　無効な値ならばPOSTを行わない。

2.SelectListItemが変更されたくない値の場合。
　→質問の2.に相当し、以下のいずれか。

a.セッション管理を行い、セッション変数(TempData)に値を保持しておく。
　b.隠しinputフィールド(TempData)に値を入れておく。

ただし、セッション管理だとクライアント側で Cookie を受け入れる設定が必要かも？
[ログインでセッションをつかうのか？　for ASP.NET MVC5](https://tech.exceedone.co.jp/asp-net/session-cookieless-session-for-asp-net-mvc5/)

隠しinputフィールドは、idとnameを同一に設定しておく必要があるそうです。
[asp.net-mvc redirecttoaction 引数 - mvcのコントローラから隠しフィールドの値を設定する方法](https://code.i-harness.com/ja-jp/q/1016dab)
[c# ヘルパー htmlヘルパー - ASP.NET MVC:隠しフィールド値がHtmlHelper.Hiddenを使用してレンダリングされない](http://code.i-harness.com/ja/q/1ecf3b)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。こちらも返信が遅れて申し訳ございません。はじめは隠しinputフィールドを使おうとしたのですが、HTMLの記述が多く(冗長的に見える)なってしまったため、専用のViewModelを作って対応しました。 しかし、大変参考になりました。